# Applying ScrollView to Image with ScaleAspectFill

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to implement a vertical only `scrollview`. When I implement it, the entire view becomes stretched horizontally because my image is set to `ScaleAspectFill`

```
    defaultImage.image = setDefaultImage
    defaultImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    defaultImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

How can I make the imageview the width of the screen and allow scroll view to only scroll vertically.

The image scrolls vertically and stretches entire view
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
```

You can change the scroll width and height as you like.

For the image:

```
self.yourImage.frame = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, width, height)
```

Comment: Even after setting all those values, the image continues to stretch past the width of  the screen

Comment: Have you tried .ScaleAspectFit ? What is the size of your image, and what of your UIImageView?

Comment: my image is currently using scaleaspectfit and cliptobounds. When i set the size of the image, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Why dont you make the image/imageView smaller, or change the contentMode, to prevent the image from stretching?